# Why does <tab> cause odd indexOf() results in Java?

Tags: java, indexof

I have a flat file of e-mail header data that I'm trying to parse for analysis. The file will always have fields in order as follows: Record Number, 1 or 2 bytes, `"From:"` followed by the sender's name and `"Sent:"` followed by the date sent.

```
1 From: Person.Name Sent: April 12, 2010
2 From:<tab>Person.Name Sent: April 30, 2011
10 From: Person.Name Sent: June 29, 2012
11 From:<tab>Person.Name Sent: July 8, 2012
```

Using `BufferedReader` I am reading a the file line-by-line and defining a substring of the Name based on all characters between the indeces of `"From:"` and `"Sent:"`.

```
String sender = inputLine.substring((inputLine.indexof("From:")+6),(inputLine.indexOf("Sent:")-1));
```

In this case, I'm grabbing everything AFTER "From: " (sixth byte excludes the word, the colon, and the space/single byte after the colon) through one LESS than the position of "Sent: " (the space before the S).

However, I'm getting unexpected output when I run the job. Some of my input data **appears** to have a tab after `"From: "` and some lines do not. When a tab is present, my output include the last two **or** three bytes of `"From: "` (when the record number is a single digit, I get `m:<tab>`, for double digit record numbers it's `om:<tab>`.

```
Person.Name
m:<tab>Person.Name        <-- single digit record number
Person.Name        
om:<tab>Person.Name       <-- double digit record number
```

EDIT: When I amend my `substring` to

```
String sender = inputLine.substring((inputLine.indexof("From:\t")+6),(inputLine.indexOf("Sent:")-1));
```

ONLY the records with a space (and not a tab) prepent the end of the `From:` to the output.

```
Person.Name        <-- records with From:<tab>
om: Person.Name    <-- records with From:<space>
```

I'm now wondering if I understand `substring` correctly. My statement above is based on an understanding of `substring(x,y)` where `x` is the start and `y` is the end of the string. Is that correct?

Since indexOf("From:") is intended to represent an integer value of 2 or 3 (depending on a 1 or 2 byte record number, e.g., `1 From:` or `10 From:`) I would think that adding a value of 6 would give me an index value that falls AFTER the `:` in index 8 or 9 from the front of the line. So why does it appear to be viewing this as an index of 5--regardless?

```
           111111111122222222222  |
 0123456789012345678901234567890  + index values
 1 From: Person.Name Sent: June
 10 From: Person.Name Sent: July
```

The tab is the only difference in the records, and while I understand that a tab character may need to be counted differently than an ASCII space character, SUBTRACTING from the index seems a little strange.

Even more interesting, if I remove the "adjustments" from the statement,

```
     String sender = inputLine.substring((inputLine.indexof("From:")),(inputLine.indexOf("Sent:")));
```

I get a `-1 out of range` exception.

Can someone please explain what's happening here? I am baffled, and can't find answers this specific in oracle's java documentation.

Comment: May be consider appending From:\\t and see.

Comment: `\\t` is the tab with escape characters? Would I then be doing `indexOf("From:\\t")`?

Comment: yes. I would give a try. But, it fails for the lines without tabs.

Comment: Based on the information you've supplied, your original `substring` is fine. (You don't need those parens around your arguments, btw, and they make it hard to read the code.) I'm having trouble (with respect!) believing what you're describing; the presence of a tab *after* the `From:` *cannot* change the result of `indexOf("From:")`, and thus *cannot* change the starting point within the string at which `substring` will extract the substring.

Comment: Revised to include more unexpected results when I look for `\\t`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, so it's not just me thinking this is some bizarre anomaly. I've never seen a tab vs. space do that before either, but being relatively novice with Java...who knows if there's something wierd I'm missing.

Comment: *"My statment above is based on an understanding of substring(x,y) where x is the start and y is the end of the string. Is that correct?"* Why ask us? [There's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). :-) But yes, assuming you wanted to extract from just after `From:<blank>` through one character *prior* to `Sent:`, your understanding is correct (based on your original code). (`substring`'s `endindex` is exclusive; the character at that point is not included in the result.)

Comment: Looking for `indexOf("Find:\\t")` looks for `Find:` followed by a backslash and the letter `t`. It does not look for `Find:` followed by a tab.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder -- copy that about the tab escape. I was misinformed. Revising my question even as we speak to reflect new results from THAT experiment.

Comment: @dwwilson66: FWIW, I don't see the point of the experiment in any case. You're searching for `"From:"`, it'll get found -- at the same location -- regardless of what (if anything) follows it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - as a Java novice, validating my theories that a "From:" followed by a space or a tab, even though not in the search string, behave differently may be a clue. The more complete of a picture I have helps me learn which questions are more or less valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating new input fields that replaced \t with a space. Then everything worked fine. What it was about the tab character that threw things off is still a mystery.